# How can I assert a delegate is called in my unit test

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I would like to asset that the correct delegate method is called depending on the result of a check in my presenter.

Having mocked out my `IdentityProvider` to return true, how would I write a test to assert `delegate?.userIsAuthenticated()` is called?

```
import Foundation
import InjectStory

protocol StartPresenterDelegate: class {
    func userIsAuthenticated()
    func userNeedsToAuthenticate()
}

class StartPresenter {
    weak var delegate: StartPresenterDelegate?
    weak var view: StartViewInterface!

    private lazy var identityProvider = Dependencies.identityProvider.inject()

    init(view: StartViewInterface) {
        self.view = view
    }

    private func checkUserAuthState() {
        if identityProvider.isAuthorized() {
            delegate?.userIsAuthenticated()
        } else {
            delegate?.userNeedsToAuthenticate()
        }
    }

}

extension StartPresenter: StartPresentation {
    func onViewDidLoad() {
        checkUserAuthState()
    }
}

extension StartPresenter {
    struct Dependencies {
        static let identityProvider = Injection<IdentityProviderProtocol>(IdentityProvider.shared)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do some trick. Create MockDelegateClass for your protocol `StartPresenterDelegate`
example:

```
class MockDelegate: StartPresenterDelegate {

    var isUserIsAuthenticatedCalled = false
    var isUserNeedsToAuthenticateCalled = false

    func userIsAuthenticated() {
        isUserIsAuthenticatedCalled = true
    }

    func userNeedsToAuthenticate() {
        isUserNeedsToAuthenticateCalled = true
    }
}
```

then in your test try to do something like that:

```
func test_MyTest() {
    // init your class StartPresenter that you wanna test
    var presenter = StartPresenter(...)
    var mockDelegate = MockDelegate()
    presenter.delegate = mockDelegate
    presenter.onViewDidLoad()

    XCTAssertTrue(mockDelegate.isUserIsAuthenticatedCalled)
    XCTAssertFalse(mockDelegate.isUserNeedsToAuthenticateCalled)
    // or change isUserIsAuthenticatedCalled and isUserNeedsToAuthenticateCalled if you expect another states
}
```

For different states you need different tests, for you it will be the easiest way to test delegate calling.

Comment: To make this even stronger, I recommend incrementing a call count instead of using plain booleans.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mock the `StartPresenterDelegate` as follows too.

```
class MockStartPresenterDelegate: StartPresenterDelegate {
   var userIsAuthenticated_wasCalled = false 

   func userIsAuthenticated() {
       userIsAuthenticated_wasCalled = true
   }
}
```

Inject `MockStartPresenterDelegate` as the delegate and check that `userIsAuthenticated_wasCalled` is true

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this way you can confirm the unit test for delegates in Swift apps